# How to reset custom input directive and its parent form to $pristine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-form

I've implemented a custom input directive - `counter` with a reset capability. The directive has `require: "ngModel"`.

I am resetting the pristine state of the directive's `ngModel` with `$setPristine()`. Unlike `$setDirty()`, `$setPristine()` does not touch the `$pristine` state of the parent form.

**Q:** How do I "notify" the parent form that this directive is no longer "dirty", such that the parent form could have its `$pristine` state reset?

Bear in mind that just calling `form.$setPristine()` is not enough as there may be other "dirty" controls in the form, which my directive wouldn't (and shouldn't) know about.

This is the directive's link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

  var original;

  ngModel.$render = function(){
    original = scope.counter = ngModel.$viewValue;
  };

  scope.up = function(){
    ngModel.$setViewValue(++scope.counter);
  };

  scope.reset = function(){
    scope.counter = original;
    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.counter);
    ngModel.$setPristine(); // this sets $pristine on the directive, but not the form
  };
}
```

And here's how it is used:

```
<div ng-form="form">
  <counter ng-model="count"></counter>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUKUOEtiOWxueD4dkmlG?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not an expert but are you sure you think it the right way? if you need to reset the form from your counter maybe you should include it in the directive ? or your counter should expose a function to be reset and this will be call by the form reset ?

Comment: I only want to notify the parent form that this directive is no longer "dirty". The form, ideally, should manage its own dirty state. I *could* also `require: "^form"`, but what do I do then? I'm not sure I understand the second suggestion to expose a function to be called by the form's reset.

Comment: can you show us your whole directive declaration.

Comment: @levi, I have attached a link to a plunker at the bottom - can you look to see if there is something that is relevant to be included in the question (I was trying to keep the code in the question to a minimum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Angular 1.3.x, there is no built-in solution.

`form.$setPristine()` sets pristine on all its child controls. ([link to code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.11/src/ng/directive/form.js#L243))

`ngModel.$setPristine()` only sets $pristine on itself ([link to code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.11/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L368))

One way to solve this is to create a directive that lives alongside a `form` directive and hijacks `form.$setDirty` to track dirty controls count. This is probably best done in a pre-link phase (i.e. before child controls start registering themselves).

```
app.directive("pristinableForm", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: ["pristinableForm", "form"],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var me = ctrls[0],
        form = ctrls[1];
      me.form = form;
      me.dirtyCounter = 0;
      var formSetDirtyFn = form.$setDirty;
      form.$setDirty = function() {
        me.dirtyCounter++;
        formSetDirtyFn();
      };
    },
    controller: function() {
      this.$notifyPristine = function() {
        if (this.dirtyCounter === 0) return;
        if (this.dirtyCounter === 1) {
          this.dirtyCounter = 0;
          if (this.form) this.form.$setPristine();
        } else {
          this.dirtyCounter--;
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Then, the custom input directive needs to `require: ["ngModel", "^pristinableForm"]` and call `pristinableForm.$notifyPristine()` in its reset function:

```
scope.reset = function(){
  if (ngModel.$dirty){
    scope.counter = original;
    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.counter);
    ngModel.$setPristine();
    pristinableForm.$notifyPristine();
  }
};
```

The usage is:

```
<div ng-form="form" pristinable-form>
  <counter ng-model="count1"></counter>
  <counter ng-model="count2"></counter>
  <input ng-model="foo" name="anotherControl">
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8OgA9DcZ46n0bJMVpAYK?p=preview)

Comment: Sounds a bit too complex to my taste. Can you please check my related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528957/re-set-all-forms-to-pristine-status-from-the-bottom-up

Answer (score 0):

This is a not so good solution. Iterate through controls attached to the form and check if there still a dirty one.

i used the method explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908096/getting-form-controls-from-formcontroller) to get the controls.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqwWwsOK8h4uoFxYu3hB?p=preview)

```
app.directive("counter", function(){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    template: '<button ng-click="up()">{{counter}}</button><button ng-click="reset()">reset</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

      var original;

      ngModel.$render = function(){
        original = scope.counter = ngModel.$modelValue;
      };

      scope.up = function(){
        ngModel.$setViewValue(++scope.counter);
      };

      scope.reset = function(){
        scope.counter = original;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.counter);
        ngModel.$setPristine();

        // check if one of the controls attached to the form is still dirty
        var dirty = false;
        angular.forEach(scope.form, function(val, key) {
            if (key[0] != '$') {
              if (val.$dirty) {
                dirty = true; 
              }
            }
        });
        if(!dirty) scope.form.$setPristine();


      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I explicitly stated that just calling `$setPristine()` on the form does not cut it, as the form may have other child controls that may be dirty. Also, the best way to do so would be to `require: "^form"`, rather than assume that `scope.form` exists.

Comment: ok i think i understand, not sure there is built-in solution for that.

Comment: I've answered my own question, but this is along the lines of what I am thinking of doing, except in your solution you are making an assumption about `form` existing on the scope. A directive's aim is to be re-usable, so it should not know in what form it resides.