# Angular Form: access input DOM node from NgModel

Tags: angularjs

I have my form in `$scope.myFormName` which contains every `NgModelController` of every input field in there.

On error, I need to scroll to `$invalid` fields.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908096/getting-form-controls-from-formcontroller) I can access the list of the fields.

But now, I'd like to scroll up to the field. For this, I need to get the associated DOM element. So I do something like:

```
document.querySelector('name=['+inputName+']');
```

which feels dirty to me. Ain't there any pointer from the `NgModel` to its related DOM element? Or ain't this *the angular way to do this*?

Comment: You can use jqulite for dom selection. Or if your elements are individual directives you have access to the dom element in the links element param. IMO this is a fine way of doing this though.

Comment: I feel Angular doesn't *want* us to do it this way. But I hardly can see an alternative there.

Comment: Why though? Angular isn't a dom manipulation library like jquery.

Comment: I also thought `document.querySelector` had low browser compatibility, otherwise what is the point of still using jQuery? But apparently it is quite compatible ... http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: Jquery is just sugared javascript, so you're really just trading a bit bigger of a library for ease of use. What I mean by my comments though is there is nothing wrong with the way you're doing it and angular itself doesn't give you many tools for dom selection stuff. The ngmodel is best used when working with a controller and the controller shouldn't know about the DOM itself. So you use whatever dom selectors you like. Personally I think the raw javascript is the best way :). I suppose a bit more angular way would be using it's `angular.element`. But I don't think that matters too much.